# How can I auto click a Value Button Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<form action='/numeric_score_vote' method='POST'>
  <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="1bc953fd382c580062da0fd050e46916">
  <input type='hidden' name='image_id' value='141687'>
  <input type='hidden' name='vote' value='up'>
  <input type='submit' value='Vote Up'>
</form>
```

So I would like to write a simple Script using Javascript and have it auto click this "Vote Up" Button immediately only once on page load. However im still new at Javascript and I dont understand how things work.

Comment: Target the element with a selector, then use `.click()`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please use a HTML validator.

Comment: Is this your page? Are you able to edit it? If so, then I fail to see why this is necessary as you could simply change the server-side code to perform the same action as `numeric_score_vote` when this page is requested. If not, then I don't know how you plan on adding any JavaScript. It's unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

it is actually fairly simple,

first of all you have to give your form an id like

```
<form id="voteup">
```

then you get your form element in javascript on your page load function which you can build with the

```
window.onload = function (){}
```

so your full example would be:

Html:

```
<form id="voteup" method="POST" action="yourphp.php">
```

And Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){


var form = document.getElementById("voteup");

form.submit();

}
```

That's it simple as that.

br,

Sebastian

Comment: *"submit() function does not work if your input button have the value submit or is of type "submit""* <- what?